# Two updatePanels and popup extender which should not disappear after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

On my `MasterPage` I have 2 update panels which are surrounded with Panels. Two of them contain 'Details View' controls and some buttons.

On the other hand, I have one `UpdatePanel` which contains image buttons and link buttons.

The idea is that I'm fetching from the database the messages ( 2 kinds), showing them on the Page. When the user clicks on a button (`LinkButton` or `ImageButton`), he or she sees a 'Popup Control'. On the popup control, he or she can see the message details and if needed, cancel them or approve.

Here is where I am stuck. If I remove the `ImageButtons` from the `UpdatePanels`, I won't be able to refresh them without a full postback.

Should I have 'popup extensions' in the `UpdatePanel` with the `ImageButtons`, but then when I click on the button from 'popup panel' - it disappears ( there is no full postback, it just disappears) - it should just change the `DetailsView` page.

How do I make it work?

Thanks in advance !

(I need this solution because I want to use a timer to refresh `LinkButtons` )

here is my code behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //here im pulling data from database and binding it with 'details view' controls, its not big deal so i think i don't have to show it?
        wyswietl_powiadomienia_o_wydarzeniach();
        wyswietl_ilosc_zaproszen_do_przyjaciol();
        wyswietl_ilosc_nieodczytanych_wiadomosci();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}


protected void ButtonWczesniej_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DetailsViewEventsRequests.PageIndex = DetailsViewEventsRequests.PageIndex - 1;
    ButtonDalej.Enabled = true;
    wyswietl_powiadomienia_o_wydarzeniach();

}
protected void ButtonDalej_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 
    DetailsViewEventsRequests.PageIndex = DetailsViewEventsRequests.PageIndex + 1;

    ButtonWczesniej.Enabled = true;
    wyswietl_powiadomienia_o_wydarzeniach();
}

protected void ButtonInvLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsViewIfFriends.PageIndex = DetailsViewIfFriends.PageIndex - 1;
}
protected void ButtonInvRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsViewIfFriends.PageIndex = DetailsViewIfFriends.PageIndex + 1;
}
```

And my aspx: (only one updatepanel with detail's view because 2nd one is very simillar)

```
<div id="NotifyAreaWhite">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="NotifyAreaDiv">
                <div id="NotifyDivMail">
                    <div id="NotifyLeftMSG"><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonNotifyMsg" runat="server"  
                            ImageUrl="~/images/msg.png" PostBackUrl="~/wiadomosci.aspx" 
                            ToolTip="Wyslij wiadomosc" /></div>
                    <div class="NotifyRight"> <asp:LinkButton ID="LabelNotifyMsgNo" runat="server"  Text="0" Font-Size="Large" PostBackUrl="~/wiadomosci.aspx"/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="NotifyDiv">
                <div id="NotifyLeftFrend" class="NotifyLeft"> <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonNotifyFrends" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/friends.png" 
                        ToolTip="Zaproszenia od znajomych." /></div>
                <div id="NotifyRightFrend" class="NotifyRight"><asp:LinkButton ID="LabelNotifyFrendsNo" runat="server" Text="0" Font-Size="Large"/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="NotifyDiv">
                <div id="NotifyLeftWyd" class="NotifyLeft"> <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonWydarzenia" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/event.png" ToolTip="Zaproszenia do wydarzen." /></div>
                <div id="NotifyRightWyd" class="NotifyRight"> <asp:LinkButton ID="LabelNotifyEventsNo" runat="server" Text="0" Font-Size="Large"/></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                     <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="PanelZaproszeniaEventy_ModalPopupExtender" 
                        runat="server"  Enabled="true" OkControlID="ButtonZamknijOkno" CancelControlID="ButtonZamknijOkno"
                        TargetControlID="ImageButtonWydarzenia" PopupControlID="PanelZaproszeniaEventy"
                        BackgroundCssClass="NotifyPageTloClass"/> //extender showing Panel
                     <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="PanelZaproszeniaEventy_ModalPopupExtenderCyfra" 
                        runat="server"  Enabled="true" OkControlID="ButtonZamknijOkno" CancelControlID="ButtonZamknijOkno"
                        TargetControlID="LabelNotifyEventsNo" PopupControlID="PanelZaproszeniaEventy"
                        BackgroundCssClass="NotifyPageTloClass"/>

                      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="PanelProsbyOznajomosc_ModalPopupExtender" 
                        runat="server"  Enabled="true" OkControlID="ButtonFrendCloseNotifier" CancelControlID="ButtonFrendCloseNotifier"
                        TargetControlID="ImageButtonNotifyFrends" PopupControlID="PanelProsbyOznajomosc"
                        BackgroundCssClass="NotifyPageTloClass"/>
                      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="PanelProsbyOznajomosc_ModalPopupExtenderCyfra" 
                        runat="server"  Enabled="true" OkControlID="ButtonFrendCloseNotifier" CancelControlID="ButtonFrendCloseNotifier"
                        TargetControlID="LabelNotifyFrendsNo" PopupControlID="PanelProsbyOznajomosc"
                        BackgroundCssClass="NotifyPageTloClass"/>
          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<asp:Panel ID="PanelZaproszeniaEventy" runat="server" Width="318px" CssClass="NotifyWydTlo" >
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelZaproszeniaEventy" runat="server" RenderMode="Block">
        <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewEventsRequests" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Charakterystyka" AutoGenerateRows="False" Height="17px" Width="313px" HorizontalAlign="Center" onitemcreated="DetailsViewEventsRequests_ItemCreated">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Zalozyciel" SortExpression="Nazwisko" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Miasto" HeaderText="Gdzie?" SortExpression="Miasto" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data_ZalozeniaWydarzenia" HeaderText="Data wyslania" SortExpression="Miasto" />
                        </Fields>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <div style="float:left;">
                                   <asp:Label ID="LabelNazwaWydarzenia" runat="server"  
                                      Text='<%# Eval("Nazwa_Wydarzenia") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:right; margin-left:5px;">
                                   <asp:Button ID="ButtonZobacz" runat="server"  CssClass="myButton" Text="Zobacz Wydarzenie" Font-Size="X-Small" Width="150px" ClientIDMode="AutoID" OnClick="ButtonZobacz_click" UseSubmitBehavior="True"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px; color:#FF5041; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                                <tr>
                                   <td>Nie masz zadnych zaproszen.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:DetailsView>
            <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonWczesniej"  Width="69px" Height="41px" runat="server" Text="<<" OnClick="ButtonWczesniej_Click" CssClass="myButton" /></td> //button previous msg
                    <td>
                      <asp:Button ID="ButtonDalej" Width="69px" Height="41px" runat="server" Text=">>"  ///button next msg
                            OnClick="ButtonDalej_Click" CssClass="myButton"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 112px;">
        <asp:Button CssClass="myButton" ID="ButtonZamknijOkno"  Width="100%"  //button closing popup
        Height="41px" runat="server" Text="ZAMKNIJ"/>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

I hope i described it well. Sorry For my weak english and some Polish words in code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i should do at the begining i made this example on empty page and try something else.. mode="Conditional" did the trick.

I should give that code  before, not that long one :)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkPanelOn" runat="server">click here to show popup</asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="PanelZaproszeniaEventy_ModalPopupExtenderCyfra" 
            runat="server"  Enabled="true" OkControlID="ButtonClose" CancelControlID="ButtonClose"
            TargetControlID="HyperLinkPanelOn" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="NotifyPageTloClass" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelPopUp" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="postback" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="postback" />
         </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonClose" runat="server" Text="Zamknij" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

So simple.. I thought it's something bigger :/